# Parsing JSONP files using R

Tags: json, r, jsonp, jsonlite

JSON newbie here. Could you please help with parsing JSON files using R. I did try jsonlite & rjson, but keep getting errors.

Below is the data retrieved via the api.

```
data <- GET("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=harry%20potter&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=10")
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
/**/_cb_findItemsByKeywords({
   "findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[
      {
         "ack":[
            "Success"
         ],
         "version":[
            "1.13.0"
         ],
         "timestamp":[
            "2016-01-29T16:36:25.984Z"
         ],
         "searchResult":[
            {
               "@count":"1",
               "item":[
                  {
                     "itemId":[
                        "371533364795"
                     ],
                     "title":[
                        "Harry Potter: Complete 8-Film Collection (DVD, 2011, 8-Disc Set)"
                     ],
                     "globalId":[
                        "EBAY-US"
                     ],
                     "primaryCategory":[
                        {
                           "categoryId":[
                              "617"
                           ],
                           "categoryName":[
                              "DVDs & Blu-ray Discs"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "galleryURL":[
                        "http:\/\/thumbs4.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mn5Agt0HFD89L7_-lqfrZZw\/140.jpg"
                     ],
                     "viewItemURL":[
                        "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/itm\/Harry-Potter-Complete-8-Film-Collection-DVD-2011-8-Disc-Set-\/371533364795"
                     ],
                     "productId":[
                        {
                           "@type":"ReferenceID",
                           "__value__":"110258144"
                        }
                     ],
                     "paymentMethod":[
                        "PayPal"
                     ],
                     "autoPay":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "postalCode":[
                        "60131"
                     ],
                     "location":[
                        "Franklin Park,IL,USA"
                     ],
                     "country":[
                        "US"
                     ],
                     "shippingInfo":[
                        {
                           "shippingServiceCost":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"0.0"
                              }
                           ],
                           "shippingType":[
                              "FlatDomesticCalculatedInternational"
                           ],
                           "shipToLocations":[
                              "US",
                              "CA",
                              "GB",
                              "AU",
                              "AT",
                              "BE",
                              "FR",
                              "DE",
                              "IT",
                              "JP",
                              "ES",
                              "TW",
                              "NL",
                              "CN",
                              "HK",
                              "MX",
                              "DK",
                              "RO",
                              "SK",
                              "BG",
                              "CZ",
                              "FI",
                              "HU",
                              "LV",
                              "LT",
                              "MT",
                              "EE",
                              "GR",
                              "PT",
                              "CY",
                              "SI",
                              "SE",
                              "KR",
                              "ID",
                              "ZA",
                              "TH",
                              "IE",
                              "PL",
                              "RU",
                              "IL"
                           ],
                           "expeditedShipping":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "oneDayShippingAvailable":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "handlingTime":[
                              "1"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "sellingStatus":[
                        {
                           "currentPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"26.95"
                              }
                           ],
                           "convertedCurrentPrice":[
                              {
                                 "@currencyId":"USD",
                                 "__value__":"26.95"
                              }
                           ],
                           "sellingState":[
                              "Active"
                           ],
                           "timeLeft":[
                              "P16DT3H12M6S"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "listingInfo":[
                        {
                           "bestOfferEnabled":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "buyItNowAvailable":[
                              "false"
                           ],
                           "startTime":[
                              "2016-01-15T19:43:31.000Z"
                           ],
                           "endTime":[
                              "2016-02-14T19:48:31.000Z"
                           ],
                           "listingType":[
                              "StoreInventory"
                           ],
                           "gift":[
                              "false"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "returnsAccepted":[
                        "true"
                     ],
                     "condition":[
                        {
                           "conditionId":[
                              "1000"
                           ],
                           "conditionDisplayName":[
                              "Brand New"
                           ]
                        }
                     ],
                     "isMultiVariationListing":[
                        "false"
                     ],
                     "topRatedListing":[
                        "true"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "paginationOutput":[
            {
               "pageNumber":[
                  "1"
               ],
               "entriesPerPage":[
                  "1"
               ],
               "totalPages":[
                  "138112"
               ],
               "totalEntries":[
                  "138112"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "itemSearchURL":[
            "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/sch\/i.html?_nkw=harry+potter&_ddo=1&_ipg=1&_pgn=1"
         ]
      }
   ]
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your data is not `json`, but it is JavaScript, `jsonp` to be exactly. If you just want to parse the JSON data you have to strip off the padding callback function.

```
req <- httr::GET("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=YOUR-APP-123456&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=harry%20potter&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=10")
txt <- content(req, "text")
json <- sub("/**/_cb_findItemsByKeywords(", "", txt, fixed = TRUE)
json <- sub(")$", "", json)
mydata <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
```

***Extra credit***: alternatively you could use an actual JavaScript engine to parse the JavaScript:

```
library(V8)
ctx <- V8::v8()
ctx$eval("var out;")
ctx$eval("function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(x){out = x;}")
ctx$source("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=YOUR-APP-123456&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=harry%20potter&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=10")
mydata <- ctx$get("out")
```

Comment: That was so helpful. Thank you so very much.

Comment: Found a link with additional info on JSONP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about?rq=1

Comment: Can you please clarify what the "$" sign signifies in the second json statement. I understand you are trying to remove the ")" at the end, but wasn't sure of the usage of $. Please clarify. json <- sub(")$", "", json)

Comment: Since the output of mydata is a list. I tried mydata2 <-  jsonlite::stream_in(file("mydata")). But that didn't work. Please let me know if the next step is to flatten mydata, before stream_in, so I can get the data as a data.frame. Basically, I just need 2 the itemId & title fields that are nested within "item.

Answer (score -1):

First, your json file seems to have a little issue. It should have started in the opening bracket "[".

I removed the text before it and I've tried this code, which worked perfectly:

```
library(rjson)
obj <- fromJSON(file = "v2.json")
```

That returned a list in `obj` with the contents of v2.json.

EDITED: Including a full functional soltion:

```
library(rjson)
library(stringr)
obj <- read.table("v2.json", sep = "\n", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "")

# Gets the first line with the string "[" ("\\" for scape)
firstline <- grep("\\[", obj[,1])[1]

# Gets the position of the string "[" in the line
fpos <- which(strsplit(obj[firstline, 1], "")[[1]] == "[")

# Gets the last line with the string "]"
lastline <- grep("\\]", obj[,1])
lastline <- lastline[length(lastline)]

# Gets the position of the string "]" in the line
lpos <- which(strsplit(obj[lastline, 1], "")[[1]] == "]")

# Changes the lines with the first "[" and the last "]" to keep the text
# between both (after "[" and before "]") if there is any.
obj[firstline, 1] <- str_sub(obj[firstline, 1], fpos)
obj[lastline, 1] <- str_sub(obj[lastline, 1], 1, lpos)

obj2 <- data.frame(obj[firstline:lastline, 1])
write.table(obj2, "v3.json", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

obj3 <- fromJSON(file = "v3.json")
```

Comment: Hi Fernando - That is the data returned via the API. I may be able to use gsub and remove the initial characters up to the first square [, but then I will also need to delete the 2 braces at the end too '})'.

Comment: Yeah, I think `gsub()` combined with a function that finds the positions of the characters "["and "]" will fit perfectly (maybe something like `which(strsplit(line, "")[[1]] ==  "[")` will work).

Comment: Thanks Fernando. Could you please help explain the which statement that you provided.

Comment: I made a mistake. It's not with `gsub()`, I was thinking in "stringr" function `str_sub()`. I edited the answer with a full solution to explain what I meant.

Comment: @ Fernando. Thanks for the detailed explanation Fernando. However, I am still getting errors when I run the code. Note: I am using a .JSON file that has the unformatted text - that I have appended to my question. Please check.